# Why is key a string in for ... in

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm writing a simple `for...in` loop in javascript, and wondering why the `key` is a string and not a number?

Why is it so, and can I change that to be a number?

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var key in array) {
   console.log(typeof key); //string
   console.log(key + 1); //expected output : 01, 11, 21...
}
```

Comment: It's probably because for y in x treats the x as an object so you can iterate through its properties

Comment: Using a foreach with arrays is a bit expensive if you want to access array elements as you'd have to parse `key` on to an int, is best to use foreach loops for objects (`{}`) and not arrays (`[]`). The standard loops for arrays are either `for(let i=..; i < ....; i++) {}` or `array.forEach(function(val, i) { })`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a string because standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)¹, they're objects with properties for the array entries, and object property names (keys) are strings, Symbols, or (soonish) private names.

You can't make it a number by default in a `for-in`, but you can convert it to a number, or use other forms such as a standard `for` or a `forEach` call:

```
for (var key = 0; key < array.length; ++k) {
    // ...
}
// ..or
array.forEach((entry, key) => {
    // ...
});
```

Using `for-in` to loop through an array is almost always an anti-pattern. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for a thorough rundown of your various options for looping through arrays.

---

¹ That's a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, and nice little explanation on your blog :).

Answer (score 3):

[Objects and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties)

> Please note that all keys in the square bracket notation are converted to String type, since ***objects in JavaScript can only have String type as key type***.

Comment: That hasn't been true for years. ES2015 introduced Symbol-named properties, and ES2019 or ES2020 will introduce private names as well. I've fixed the quote above in the linked article.

Answer (score 2):

Object property names are *always* strings.

Use `+`, `parseInt`, `JSON.parse` or any other standard method to convert a string to a number if you want a number.

```js
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

for (var key in array) {
  console.log(+key + 1);
}
```

Comment: *"Object property names are always strings."* That hasn't been true for years... :-)